# how to set label and line the same color in gnuplot

Tags: colors, label, gnuplot, linestyle

Very simple stuff. I want a function, say function f, to be plotted with a particular color. I also want a piece of label saying "function f color" which is also displayed in that color.

I am trying this so far:

```
set style line 1 lw 3 lc 1
set label "AC" at 0, 70 textcolor 1
```

but apparently the "lc" and "textcolor" follows different specs, and it complains:

```
"trolo4.pl", line 8: colorspec option not recognized
```

any help would be great!

Answer (score 11):

Try this instead:

```
set label "AC" at 0, 70 textcolor linetype 1
```

or

```
set label "AC" at 0, 70 textcolor linespec 1
```

Read the manual in `gnuplot> help label` to learn more.

Comment: Nice.  I didn't realize you could use `linespec` or `linetype` there.

Answer (score 8):

The answer by @holygeek works fine.  Coming from python, I find that it is often nice to be a little more explicit.

```
set style line 1 lw 1 lc rgb "red"
set label "AC" at 0, 70 tc rgb "red"
```

Note that the set of color names recognized by your gnuplot is system dependent (see `show colornames` for a complete list).  To achieve complete system independence, you can use the `#RRGGBB` version.  e.g. red is `'#ff0000`, green is `#00ff00` and blue is `#0000ff`.  of course, you can make up all sorts of interesting colors (again, see `show colornames` for a list of pre-defined colors and their equivalent `#.....`)

for more info, also see `help colorspec`