# Set variable textcolor and point color with labels style in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

Related to [how to set label and line the same color in gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11220231/how-to-set-label-and-line-the-same-color-in-gnuplot) - but not quite the same... Using this code:

```
set style line 1 linetype 1 linewidth 2 pointtype 3 linecolor rgb "aquamarine"
set style line 2 linetype 1 linewidth 2 pointtype 3 linecolor rgb "blue"
set style line 3 linetype 1 linewidth 2 pointtype 3 linecolor rgb "coral"

set xrange [0:3]
set yrange [0:3]

# function to get style index for coloring:
getCol(x) = (x==0)?1:((x==1)?2:3);

plot \
  '-' using ($1+0.5):($2+0.5):(getCol($2)) with impulses \
    lc variable notitle, \
  "" using ($1+0.5):($2+0.5):(stringcolumn(2)):(getCol($2)) with labels \
    textcolor variable point linestyle 1 pointtype 7 lc variable \
    font ",6" offset character 1.0,character 1.0  notitle
0 0
1 1
1.5 1
2 2
e
0 0
1 1
1.5 1
2 2
e
```

... I get this output:

[image: gnuplot-out]

It looks like everything is fine for coloring the `impulses` - however for the `labels`, the approach seemingly works - but it's as if the colors are read from a different index ?!

So, how do I get the points and the labels to have the same variable color, using the same function - as the impulse lines? This is on gnuplot 4.6 patchlevel 1...

Comment: This issue is fixed in the newly released 4.6 patchlevel 4. Just add the line `set style increment user` before plotting, and you'll get the expected result (the same as in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18368864/2604213)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The color index for the `impulses` is used to select a line style, while for the `labels` the line type is used. This behaviour is still present in the current development version. According to the documentation, the behaviour for the `labels` is correct. `help linecolor variable` says: "`lc variable` tells the program to use the value read from one column of the input data as a linetype index... Text colors can be set similarly using `tc variable`". Bug, feature or wrong documentation?

As a workaround you can use `lc palette` and an appropriately defined `palette`:

```
set style line 1 linetype 1 linewidth 2 pointtype 3 linecolor rgb "aquamarine"
set style line 2 linetype 1 linewidth 2 pointtype 3 linecolor rgb "blue"
set style line 3 linetype 1 linewidth 2 pointtype 3 linecolor rgb "coral"

set palette defined (1 "aquamarine", 2 "blue", 3 "coral")
unset colorbox
set xrange [0:3]
set yrange [0:3]

# function to get style index for coloring:
getCol(x) = (x==0)?1:((x==1)?2:3)

unset key
plot \
  '-' using ($1+0.5):($2+0.5):(getCol($2)) with impulses lc variable, \
  '' using ($1+0.5):($2+0.5):(stringcolumn(2)):(getCol($2)) with labels \
    tc palette point ls 1 pt 7 lc palette offset 1,1
0 0
1 1
1.5 1
2 2
e
0 0
1 1
1.5 1
2 2
e
```

This gives the result:
[image]

I hope that workaround works also in your real case. If for some reason you can't redefine the palette, you can use `lc rgb variable`, in which case the last column must be an integer representation of the respective rgb color:

```
set style line 1 linetype 1 linewidth 2 pointtype 3 linecolor rgb "aquamarine"
set style line 2 linetype 1 linewidth 2 pointtype 3 linecolor rgb "blue"
set style line 3 linetype 1 linewidth 2 pointtype 3 linecolor rgb "coral"

set xrange [0:3]
set yrange [0:3]

rgb(r,g,b) = 65536 * int(r) + 256 * int(g) + int(b)
rgb1 = rgb(2, 215, 245) # something like aquamarine
rgb2 = rgb(0, 0, 255)
rgb3 = rgb(245,140,2)
getCol(x) = (x==0)?rgb1:((x==1)?rgb2:rgb3)

unset key
plot \
  '-' using ($1+0.5):($2+0.5):(getCol($2)) with impulses \
    lc rgb variable, \
  '' using ($1+0.5):($2+0.5):(stringcolumn(2)):(getCol($2)) with labels \
    tc rgb variable point ls 1 pt 7 lc rgb variable offset 1,1
0 0
1 1
1.5 1
2 2
e
0 0
1 1
1.5 1
2 2
e
```

You may only need to tweek the rgb values.

However, I will bring up this discussion on the gnuplot mailinglist to see if this is really a bug, or whatever.

Comment: Many thanks @Christoph - great answer; by accident, I discovered this same `set palette`/`unset colorbox` workaround, so it works in my test case as well. But it's great to have learned about the `lc rgb variable` approach. Thanks again - cheers!

Comment: @sdaau It takes some time to discover all the different possibilities which `gnuplot` offers to do the very same things `:)` Good to hear that it helped you.