# Gnuplot lables in RGB colors read from data line

Tags: gnuplot

Related to [Set variable textcolor and point color with labels style in gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368307/set-variable-textcolor-and-point-color-with-labels-style-in-gnuplot) but not quite the same. I have a set of data in the file "test.dat":

```
   643.8 0.09417 28.9 00  24 255 0
   483.1 0.09232 28.0 01  255 0 120
   518.5 0.08943 29.6 02  11 65 255
```

I want a 3D plot where the first three comlumns are interpreted as x y z coordinates and the fourth column as a label/point symbol and then I want the label color coded in RGB which should be taken from the 5. 6. and 7th column. I try this:

```
rgb(r,g,b) = 65536 * int(r) + 256 * int(g) + int(b)
splot "test.dat" u 1:2:3:4:(rgb($5/255,$6/255,$7/255)) with labels tc rgb variable notitle
```

but the labels appear in black:

[image: X11 Window of gnuplot showing three positioned labels in black instead of inteded rgb colors]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have been close, but why do you divide your column values by 255?

Some comments:

- In the example below I used, e.g. `column(5)` instead of the shorter `$5`, because in some cases you might have to escape `$` and use `\$5` instead. So, `column(5)` is longer but "universal". And instead of `5` you could also use a variable.
- it's not necessary to use `int()`. gnuplot will truncate.
- you can also use hexadecimal numbers `0x10000` and `0x100` to multiply your R,G,B values with (easier to remember and less prone to typos).

**Script:**

```
### variable label color from R,G,B columns
reset session

$Data <<EOD
643.8 0.09417 28.9 00  24 255   0
483.1 0.09232 28.0 01 255   0 120
518.5 0.08943 29.6 02  11  65 255
EOD

rgb(colR,colG,colB) = 0x10000*column(colR) + 0x100*column(colG) + column(colB)

splot $Data u 1:2:3:4:(rgb(5,6,7)) w labels tc rgb var
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot, this is all very helpful!