# How to change the color of a label in gnuplot

Tags: label, gnuplot

Everything is in the title.
My MWE is:

```
set term post eps color enhanced "Times-Roman" 18
set encoding utf8

a = 0.5
f(x) = a*x/(1 + a*x)
c(x) = 0.95
x1=38

set xrange [0:100]
set yrange [0:1.2]
set arrow 1 from x1,graph 0 to x1,f(x1) lt 2 lc 3 nohead
set label 1 at x1,graph 0 "{/Symbol q_1}" textcolor 3 offset 0.5,0.75 
set label 2 at 0,0.95 "0.95" textcolor 7 offset -3.5,0 

set output 'test-label.eps' 
plot f(x) with line lw 2 lc 3 ,\
c(x) with line lw 2 lc 7
```

I would like to have \theta_1 in blue and 0.95 in red, but when I used this code (which I got from gnuplot 5.0 manual, p 133) I get the error :
colorspec option not recognized

Any hint welcomed

Comment: The doc for `set label` gives you a bunch of examples what a `<colorspec>` is, like: `textcolor lt 7`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/11220408/2604213

Comment: @Christoph It is OK, Thanks a lot. I read "{textcolor <colorspec>}", but not the following pages and I thought that <colorspec> was the color, it was dumb. Sorry for the trouble